How to install Google Chrome on Kali Linux ARM64 Virtual Machine on macOS host?
I'm currently facing an issue with installing Google Chrome on my Kali Linux virtual machine and would appreciate some help.
Setup:

Host OS: macOS with ARM architecture
Virtualization: VMware hypervisor
Guest OS: Kali Linux

Issue: I'm trying to install Google Chrome,
but I can find .deb packages only for AMD64 architecture. 
When I attempt to install the package, I receive the following error:
dpkg: error processing archive google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (arm64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

I have managed to install Chromium, but I specifically need Google Chrome for my tasks. Unfortunately, I can't find a stable version of Google Chrome for ARM architecture.
Questions:

Is there a way to install Google Chrome on an ARM64 Kali Linux VM?
Are there any alternative methods or workarounds
to achieve this on my current setup?

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

are you using kali for daliy use? because kali is a distro for pentesting, you should pick a different distro. if you aren't using kali for daily use then could you please in your question explain why you need chrome specifically for pentesting

Hi, yes. i have it as a daily use and i have all my operations, bookmarks from google chrome there, it is very important for me.

As @juliethefoxcoon has stated using a linux distribution designed for penetration testing should not be used as a daily driver!  There is a Chrome designed for ARM, but you'd have better luck finding it on a general purpose Linux like Ubuntu or Debian.  The repositories for Kali Linux have been stripped/cut-down to prevent people from using it as a daily driver.

I realized something, no one has an answer to my question. :c

@juliethefoxcoon The fact that the user is using Kali Linux for something that may not be the main purpose of the distribution may be true, but that should not make the question unanswerable.  In other words, saying "Don't use Kali Linux for this" is not a valid solution to the issue.

Chrome on arm64 is available only for Windows and Mac. Google hasn't released an aarch64 build of Chrome for Linux, yet.
If you don't need to synchronise bookmarks, passwords, etc. you may try to install Chromium. It's released in several formats, including Flatpak on https://flathub.org
